# Simple mysql query (i think) - select multiple rows into 1 field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, **Profiles** and **ProfileInformation**.

Any profile may have multiple entries in ProfileInformation.

I am trying to create a query that takes all of the profile information for a specific profile and put it in to a single field, for example:

Profile[0] has 3 corresponding records in ProfileInformation, lets say phone numbers.  I would like to return a result set like:

ID, AllProfileInformation

or

0, 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890

1, 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890

Something along the lines of
SELECT Profiles.ID, (SELECT pi.Values FROM ProfileInformation pi WHERE pi.ID = Profiles.ID) as AllProfileInformation FROM Profiles

Comment: This is the closest I have come, but is this the best way?


SELECT Profiles.ID, CONCAT_WS(' ',(SELECT pi.Values FROM ProfileInformation pi WHERE pi.ID = Profiles.ID LIMIT 0,1),(SELECT pi.Values FROM ProfileInformation pi WHERE pi.ID = Profiles.ID LIMIT 1,1)) as AllProfileInformation FROM Profiles

Comment: It is possible a single entry could have 50, I can't imagine doing that n number of times is the most effective way to do this.  I only need to run the query once to collect some information, so it doesn't necessiarly have to be the most efficient query, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the mysql specific [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
select p.id, group_concat(pi.Values separator ' ') as AllProfileInformation
from profiles p
  inner join profileinformation pi on (pi.ID = p.ID)
group by pi.id
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, i knew there had to be a better way.  thank you.

Comment: and if anyone cares, I had to add GROUP BY p.id to select many

Answer (score 1):

[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is what you're looking for.